# Aligning and Scaling Images in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView that I'm adding ImageViews to and randomly putting drawables as the resources to generate a grid such as the one pictured below.

I want the images to scale so that the only gap between them will be the padding and I also want to match the spacing that it is putting between the columns, for the rows so that the gridView will always be a square that fits to the width of the screen(plus the margins). The minimum gap between the images will be the padding that I set so if the screen is big or small the images will scale up or down to fit the gridview to the width.

So how would I do this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:columnWidth= "50dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true">

</GridView>
```

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
            randomPosition = rng.nextInt(gridSize);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            } 
            else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imgSet();
            return imageView;
    }

    public void imgSet(){
        if (diff == 1){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[randomPosition]);
        }
        if (diff == 2){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds2[randomPosition]);
        }
        if (diff == 3){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds3[randomPosition]);
        }
    }
```

[image: My GridView filled with imageViews displaying circle drawables]

Answer (score 0):

if Image Scaling is your issue, you can try scaling imagees to fit into the imageView and putting them on grid..

try android:scaleType="fitXY"

try other options in scaleType also as per your needs

Comment: Would there be a way to match the height of the grid to the width?

Comment: also I need to set the scale type in the code where the image view is created rather than in the xml so I'm not sure how to set the scale type, I see that the type I want would be fit center

Comment: @MDubzem if you need set it by code use yourimageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); [ Here is the dev link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)